# Example code that embeds IronPython in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, ironpython

I'd like to do SharePoint development with IronPython, but I haven't seen any examples where IronPython is embedded in SharePoint.

Does anyone have a working example that would get me started?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by embedded in SharePoint?  ipy scripts turned into assemblies should behavior properly wherever their C# or VB.Net brethren are used (assuming the IronPython support assemblies are referencable.

I personally love using it as a more powerful scripted stsadm solution since it is hard to do Powershell error handling correctly with SharePoint.